# Incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [2]'

Tags: c++

```
struct abc_ElementD_t{
int numberofele;
int numeleVA[2]; // Problem should be here
int numeleNY;

abc_ElementD_t(
void
)
:
numberofele(0),
numeleVA(0), // problem should be here
numeleNY(0),
{
}
};
```

Can anyone help me figure out? Thanks 
I got error incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int[2]'

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list initializer like this , the error is pretty clear as the compiler said int[2] is not an int so incompatible assignment

```
abc_ElementD_t(
void
)
:
numberofele(0),
numeleVA{0,0}, // here
numeleNY(0),
{
}
};
```